# Redirection Plugin WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I'm using [redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) and I'd like to redirect traffic if keyword 'arizona' or 'az' is present:

```
https://www.example.com/example.php?Action=1&k=luxury-wellness-centers-in-arizona&PageID=348372
```

Any url that contains 'arizona' or 'az' after https://www.example.com/example.php should be redirected to https://www.example.com/arizona

I tried the following so far. But it's not working

```
^/example\.php\?Action.*[?&]k=.*?(?:arizona|az).*$
^https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/example\.php\?Action=1&k=.*?(?:arizona|az).*$
^https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/example\.php\?Action.*[?&]k=.*?(?:arizona|az).*$
```

I don't know what could be changed to have it work with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

Note, the *(?i)* will toggle-on case-insensitive mode.

```
(?i)^https://www\.example\.com/example\.php\?.*(?:az|arizona).*$
```

This will match the following values

```
https://www.example.com/example.php?Action=1&k=luxury-wellness-centers-in-arizona&PageID=348372
https://www.example.com/example.php?Action=1&k=luxury-wellness-centers-in-az&PageID=348372
https://www.example.com/example.php?Action=1&k=luxury-wellness-centers-in-ARIZONA&PageID=348372
https://www.example.com/example.php?Action=1&k=luxury-wellness-centers-in-AZ&PageID=348372
https://www.example.com/example.php?Arizona
https://www.example.com/example.php?AZ
```

And, not these

```
https://www.example.com/example.php
https://www.example.com/example.php?Action=1&PageID=348372
```